# LazyInitializationException when accessing collection in Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I'm reading some entities with [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(…);
List<Entity> list = (List<Entity>) criteria.list();
```

Now I'm iterating over this list and want to send every object inside a `Runnable` to an `Executor`. I therefore use a `RunnableBean`.

```
for (Entity entity : list) {
    IRunnableBean runnableBean = (IRunnableBean) 
        applicationContext.getBean("myRunnableBean", IRunnableBean.class);
    runnableBean.setEntity(entity);
    executor.execute(runnableBean);
}
```

The `RunnableBean` looks like this:

```
RunnableBean implements IRunnableBean {

    // Setter

    @Transactional
    void run() {
        entity.getMyCollection();
    }
}
```

When I'm accessing the collection, I'm getting a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` (`no session or session was closed`).

In Spring's log I see that the transactional method `run()` is correctly added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using [Spring's OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html). If so, this behaviour is expected. Filter puts the database connection in the thread local context which is not available in your `RunnableBean`.

As `myCollection` isn't loaded eagerly, Spring does not have access to the database connection inside `RunnableBean` and can't load it. You need to:

- create an enclosing session wrapper in your `RunnableBean`;
- pass the id of your collection to the `RunnableBean` instead of passing object and load the collection inside `RunnableBean`

Alternatively, you can make your entity to load `myCollection` eagerly but this will make the overall loading process slower.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line within your already written `for` loop:

```java
Hibernate.initialize(entity.getMyCollection());
```

This is load the collection eagerly instead of lazily: no `LazyInitializationException` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would also guess (like @mindas) that the transaction is not available in your bean because it runs in a different thread than the one that holds the transaction. As far as my experience goes spring also uses thread locals to resolve scoped proxies, so these won't work either in a bean that is run asynchronously.

Basically I would try to avoid running logic that requires a transaction in an asynchronous fashion, since asynchronous calls run for a longer time (otherwise, why use async calls?) and this will block the transaction and/or lead to timeouts.

The criteria api from jpa offers ways to fetch a relation eagerly only for a specific query. Maybe that could be a choice? Otherwise accessing the size() method of a collection will initialize it.